# IO stream interface in C

Tags: c, interfaces, stream-processing

When writing a library (eg. for dealing with JPEG or PNG files), the first thing library author needs to provide is an abstraction over FILE* (to allow also reading from plain memory, pipe, socket, http...).

Thus something like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef long long offset_t;

struct _src {
  /* vtable */
  const struct _src_ops *ops;
  /* hold the actual FILE* in the case of file stream */
  void *data;
};

/* stream operations */
struct _src_ops {
  /** open stream. Return true on success */
  bool (*open)(struct _src *src, const char *fspec);
  /** close stream. Return true on success */
  bool (*close)(struct _src *src);
  /** Returns the actual size of buffer read (<=bsize), or 0 upon error */
  size_t (*read)(struct _src *src, void *buf, size_t bsize);
  /** seek to a relative position in stream. Returns true on success */
  bool (*seek)(struct _src *src, offset_t offset);
  /** Return current offset in file, -1 on error */
  offset_t (*tell)(struct _src *src);
};
```

Is this a good design for generic streams (we'll assume seek capabilities for simplicity) ? I'd like the interface to be as solid as possible, so I am interested in comment on the error handling here.

For instance, consider:

```
bool (*open)(struct _src *src, const char *fspec);
```

Internally my library will handle only two states: `true` or `false`. It will be on application-level user to handle the different possible error type (possibly makes a different error message whether this is ENOENT or EPERM issue).

Let's also consider this API:

```
size_t (*read)(struct _src *src, void *buf, size_t bsize);
```

The error handling is now a little less obvious, another alternative API could have been:

```
bool (*read)(struct _src *src, void *buf, size_t *bsize);
```

where `bsize` would serve as both input value and output value (same goes for `offset_t (*tell)(struct _src *src)`).

I've defined `offset_t` to be `long long`, is there an impact if the vast majority of file process is under the 32bits limit ? (eg. I could also define an alternate API with `offset_t` be simply `long`).

Does it makes sense to also separate `_src` from `_src_ops` for such simple case ?

So my question is: is my interface clear enough for application level programmer ?

Comment: wonder what's the point of reposting [prior deleted question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/415382/31260)

Comment: Question with -4 points, never gets any attention.

Comment: It's not a good question for this website, so it gets downvoted. Deleting and reposting doesn't change that fact.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic states: "Requirements, architecture, and design", which points to "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design". Would you care detailing what you found "it's not a good question for this website" in my post ?

Comment: There is only one way to tell if your design works for your intended users: put it in front of them and see what they complain about.

Comment: Design reviews are on topic, so I wrote an answer to the question. But I would have answered the original question had you not deleted it. It was the edit that made an answer possible, not the reposting.

Answer (score 0):

Emulating OOP in C always gets a bit tricky, but your general approach is fine. A lot here depends on your assumptions about which kinds of data structures are common, and how the data flows through your software.

- are there a couple of vtables that will be widely reused, or will there be many one-off vtables?
- is it necessary to have access to a vtable before a source object exists?
- how will your library react to errors? Does it have to support some kind of error recovery, or will it just stop everything and return to the application?

If you expect to reuse vtables and might need access to vtables before an object exist, then a separate vtable structure like you used is sensible. If you don't need prior access and the vtable is small or if vtables are rarely shared then combining function pointers and data into the same struct sounds more sensible.

Your `bool open(_src* src, const char* fspec)` operation is tricky. As written, this makes very strong assumptions: that a `src` object already exists, and that it can be initialized from a string argument. This depends on the data flow of your application. Quite possibly, your library does not know the correct source type up front. Not all sources are reasonably representable as a string, e.g. in-memory buffers. It is also questionable whether the object can exist prior to the open method being called.

So instead of this …

```c
struct _src src;
src.data = NULL;
src.ops = &FILE_SYSTEM_OPS;
bool ok = src.ops.open(&src, "file:///foo.png");
```

… you might prefer to have the application figure out the correct ops/type:

```c
struct _src src;
bool ok = some_callback_to_let_the_app_figure_it_out(&src, "file:///foo.png");
```

Or if the vtable is embedded into the object:

```c
struct _src* src = some_callback_to_let_the_app_figure_it_out("file:///foo.png");
bool ok = src != NULL;
```

Using such a callback also elegantly moves the responsibility to handle errors to the application.

Should you know all possible types up front so that your library can select the appropriate type given a particular `fspec` string, then you do not need vtables and could simply use an enum to dispatch your operations – likely both simpler and faster.

There is less to be said about the other methods. Don't use meaningless types like `long` unless you really don't care about it's size, or if you are targetting a particular platform. If you need a specific size, use something like `uint32_t`. If you want an array index (which a seek position essentially is), consider `size_t` (for absolute offsets) or maybe `ptrdiff_t` (for relative offsets).

In your read() method, it is fine to communicate the number of read characters via an out argument. This could be required e.g. when reading zero bytes is not an error, but e.g. an indication of EOF. However, it might be less bug-prone to keep the input “buffer capacity” separate from the output “buffer size”.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on `some_callback_to_let_the_app_figure_it_out`. Here is how I understand it on my side: `struct _src {
bool (*some_callback_to_let_the_app_figure_it_out)(struct _src *src, const char *fspec);`. So it would be called with `bool ok = src.some_callback_to_let_the_app_figure_it_out(&src, "file:///foo.png");`. Is this what you meant ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the following is pretty bad:

```
/** Returns the actual size of buffer read (<=bsize), or 0 upon error */
  size_t (*read)(struct _src *src, void *buf, size_t bsize);
```

A return of `0` does not distinguish between end-of-file and error.